# How to add tabs in tablayout using an String Array or arraylist?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

I have a `fragment A`, in which there is a `gridView` which have some item, now when I click on one of the items, It creates a new instance of `Fragment B` with some `arguments` (An String Array).

Then in the `onCreateView` I'm getting this string array, and now

> I want to set this as the tabs of the tab layout.

For this, I have created a `TabFragment` for the layout of each tab(All are same)And a `tabViewPagerAdapter`

And In `Fragment B` I am getting the extra Arguments (a String array) and setting it to the tablayout.

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {
        // handle your code here.
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bundle is getting the thing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        tabs = bundle.getStringArray("key");
        for (String s: tabs){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// it is showing the toast with all elements of the array
        }
    }

    //viewpager
    ViewPager viewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.book_viewpager);


    TabLayout tabLayout = includeView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    TabViewPagerAdapter adapter = new TabViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs);//this tab is generating null pointer exception but tab have elements in it.
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true);

    return view;
}
```

And this is how I'm sending the argument with `Fragment A`

```
 String text = (String) tempText.getText();

 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
 if (text.equalsIgnoreCase("science")){
      bundle.putStringArray("key",science); // Put anything what you want
  }else {
    bundle.putStringArray("key",engineering); // Put anything what you want
    }

 BooksFragment fragment = new BooksFragment();
 fragment.setArguments(bundle);

 assert getFragmentManager() != null;

 getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.main_container, fragment).commit();
```

But nothing seems to work. And the commented line in Fragment B, is invoking null pointer exception, in spite of `tabs` have elements in it.

> What I want to achieve is that, while clicking the `grid view` items of the `Fragment A`, I can change the tabs of the `tablaout` of `Fragment B`, if there is another way, please write

Logcat

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>           at com.medit.persuaeture.Adapters.TabViewPagerAdapter.getCount(TabViewPagerAdapter.java:27)
>           at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:526)
>           at com.medit.persuaeture.Fragments.Main.BooksFragment.onCreateView(BooksFragment.java:63)

TabViewPagerAdapter'

```
public class TabViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private String[] title;

public TabViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, String[] titleArray) {
    super(manager);
    this.title = titleArray;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return TabFragment.getInstance(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return title.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return title[position];
    }
}
```

Comment: If there anything which I didn't include please comment.

Comment: How about using `getChildFragmentManager` instead of `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()`?

Comment: No, nothing happened, same problem, NPE

Comment: Can I see the logcat? And btw, how are you inflating your fragment B view?

Comment: I am using a `TabFragment` for inflating and a `TabViewPagerAdapter` for swiping and changing the tabs. and I am adding some part of logcat to the question.

Comment: Can you add your TabViewPagerAdapter code as well just to be sure

Comment: it is clean and simple, yet adding it, :D

Comment: seems good. The only thing that can force NPE in your case is when bundle is null. Just to be on the safe side, initialize your tabs array into an empty one to avoid the NPE. And try to debug it and see if there is indeed a case wherein your arguments is null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174485/discussion-between-meditat-and-tompee).